# Django Filefield UnicodeDecodeError on model.save

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unicode, django-models

None of the similar questions on StackOverflow seem to have the same problem as me, I've only found http://qnundrum.com/question/766895, which was never answered. I'm running Python 3.3 and Django 1.6, so usually Unicode stuff is automatically taken care of. Appreciate any help I can get.

I'm trying to save automatically generated ebooks to my database for later retrieval. Some of the books contain non-ASCII characters. I've got the generation down, .mobi and .epub's work as intended. Here's models.py:

```
class StoryDownload(models.Model):
    text = models.OneToOneField('stories.Story', primary_key=True, related_name='downloads')
    epub = models.FileField(upload_to='epub/', blank=True, null=True)
    mobi = models.FileField(upload_to='mobi/', blank=True, null=True)

    def update_downloads(self):
        #code to generate epub and mobi files from text
        ...
        self.epub = File(open('filename.epub'), 'r'))
        self.mobi = File(open('filename.mobi'), 'r'))
        self.save()
        ...
```

The error comes on `self.save()` is what confuses me; if the files are accepted as Django File objects, then why can't I save them?

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\braces\views\_access.py" in dispatch
  64.             request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\guardian\mixins.py" in dispatch
  190.             **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  228.         return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  171.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\dev\akrito\chapters\views.py" in form_valid
  69.         self.chapter.story.save()
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\dev\akrito\stories\models.py" in save
  87.             self.downloads.update_downloads()
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\dev\akrito\stories\models.py" in update_downloads
  135.         self.save()
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  632.                       for f in non_pks]
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in <listcomp>
  632.                       for f in non_pks]
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
  252.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in save
  49.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in _save
  203.                         for chunk in content.chunks():
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\base.py" in chunks
  76.             data = self.read(chunk_size)
File "C:\Users\Chris\Envs\stories\lib\encodings\cp1252.py" in decode
  23.         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /stories/2/1/e/
Exception Value: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 123: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: It looks like you are running on Windows; if your file names have non-ASCII characters, this could be the cause of your exception. Can you confirm the file names?

Comment: Filenames do not have non-ASCII characters. I'm testing with "The Trial" by Kafka, so filenames are 'the-trial.epub' and 'the-trial.mobi'. Inside the files, there are non-ASCII characters though.

Comment: How are you converting?

Comment: Pandoc and Kindlegen. The files themselves work fine, I can open them, view on devices, etc, the problem is in getting the db to take them.

Comment: `self.epub = File(open('the-trial.epub'), 'r', encoding='utf-8'))` and the same with the mobi, still doesn't work. The epub is 100% in utf-8 (Pandoc docs), and from what I can find it seems 95% likely the .mobi file is as well.

Comment: Ah, the binary fix was it, had to switch to 'rb'. Since Mobi and Epub's are zips, have to open in binary (also shouldn't define encoding then). Eryksun, if you make it an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a text file you need to call `open` with the desired `encoding`. The default encoding is `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, which is why the traceback shows it attempting to decode using the Windows 1252 codepage.

That said, MOBI and EPUB files are zipped archives that should be opened in binary mode, e.g. `open('filename.epub', 'rb')`.